# OpenSearch alway down in Magento 2.4.6. Killed by oom-kill

Tags: magento2.4.6, opensearch

I'm having problems with OpenSearch in Magento 2.4.6.

After 1 or 2 weeks, OpenSerach crashes and causes the store's products to disappear.
I'm not able to resolve this. I thought it could be the machine's memory but I hired an AWS Linux 2023 t3a.large with 8Gb of RAM and it still crashes.

I set the Xms and Xms of jvm.options to up to 4GB in the opensearch folder and enabled 'bootstrap.memory_lock: true' in the opensearch.yml file, but it didn't help either.

When it goes down and checks the status I get this message:

[image]

Comment: Check the server log with help of server team.

Comment: Please review this url - https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/t3/  
There is NO mention in this information about using t3 for a production instance.  
It does mention - run your code repositories and development and test environments.

Comment: To try to survive in your t3a world, Additional DB information request, please. 
# cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide RAM conserving suggestions.

Comment: T3a.large has 8GB RAM, 5 GBPS Bandwidth, 2 vCPUS. Before update to Magento 2.4.6 we used a t2.medium instance with 4GB and everything works fine.

Comment: You may find this URL helpful.  https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/4419942355725-Switching-to-OpenSearch-for-Adobe-Commerce-on-Cloud-2-4-4